# How to fetch elements from a string NOT matching a given array of elements

Tags: php, regex, string-matching, regex-negation

Say I have this blacklist of elements:

```
$bl = array(
    'sit',
    'consectetur',
    'adipiscing',
    ',',
    '.',
    ' ',
);
```

and this string:

```
$subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
```

What would be a good way to get an array of each element in that string except those from the blacklist ?

Comment: Explain why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you don't display an attempt at the problem yourself.

Comment: It wasn't from me, but I'd assume that it's because you haven't shown what you [**have already tried**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), showcasing your attempt in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Convert your string to an array of words, then use `array_diff()` on it. That'll get you started. Then you need to worry about upper-/lowercase letters, punctuation marks, etc. Let us know if you have any trouble.

Comment: @ctwheels I have not tried anything since I don't know at all how to achieve this, which is the reason of my question... Why would you need that anyway, the question is perfectly concise.

Comment: @user285001 I completely agree, don't get me wrong. I'm just stating why you've been downvoted. It's very common for this to happen because SO is flooded with questions that lack information (regardless of what was or wasn't tried). I'd suggest posting all your **relevant** code and just create at least a couple of *fake* trials and say "I tried this but it's not giving me the expected results". SO isn't a code-writing service and that's why users are quick to respond to questions with downvotes. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt for more information. People love to link that article.

Comment: Do you want the word `deposit` to be reduced to `depo` (because of `sit` in the blacklist) or do you want it to remain whole because the whole word is not in the blacklist array?  This is a critical point when deciding on the best method for your project.  As others have said, you must add your coding attempt to your question -- this is not just something cute that volunteers write under questions, this is a requirement for all questions on StackOverflow.  Normally I wouldn't answer this question because it doesn't yet qualify, but you bad / sub-optimal answers offered to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a definitive answer with the given information. Like how do you define an element? Are the spaced, comas, periods in your block list so as just to leave out everything but a word, or are they elements and you just happen to not want those particular ones? What about other punctuation? Here is a possible solution but it would depend on some unknown factors as to whether it will work for you:

```
$bl = [
    'sit',
    'consectetur',
    'adipiscing',
];
$subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';

// REMOVE PUNCTUATION. Add punctuation you want to omit in the brackets
$subject = preg_replace( "#[,.]#", '', $subject );

// GET DIFFERENCE BETWEEN TWO ARRAYS
$array = array_diff(
        preg_split( "#\s+#", $subject ),
        $bl
);

print_r( $array );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it all with one call of `preg_split()`.  The pattern takes a little preparation first, it will effectively treat each entry in the blacklist array and treat it like a delimiter.  The 4th parameter of the call, ensures that empty elements are discarded from the output array.

([Pattern Demo / Official Breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/Vw2a6M/4))

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b365f5b1870020b318a7a3118704a960aee8515b))

```
$blacklist=['sit','consectetur','adipiscing',',','.',' '];
$subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';

foreach($blacklist as &$entry){  // & means modify by reference, this means $blacklist (not its copy) will be altered
    if(ctype_alpha($entry)){
        $entry="\b{$entry}\b"; // wrap in word boundaries (str_replace doesn't offer this accuracy)
    }else{
        $entry="\Q{$entry}\E"; // make non-word literal, no word boundaries required
    }
}
$pattern='/'.implode('|',$blacklist).'/i';
// generates: '/\bsit\b|\bconsectetur\b|\badipiscing\b|\Q,\E|\Q.\E|\Q \E/i'
var_export(preg_split($pattern,$subject,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));  // this treats each blacklisted words as a delimiter
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Lorem',
  1 => 'ipsum',
  2 => 'dolor',
  3 => 'amet',
  4 => 'elit',
)
```

---

As a less flexible alternative method that doesn't use regex, you can leverage the magic of `str_word_count()` -- this offers the desired output for your sample input data because of how the `str_word_count()` treats punctuation.  `array_diff()` just removes any elements that exist in both arrays:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UhkV4))

```
$bl = array('sit', 'consectetur','adipiscing', ',', '.', ' ');  // the , . and space elements could be removed here
$subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';

var_export(array_diff(str_word_count($subject,1),$bl));  // if you use strtolower() on $subject, you will get case-insensitive comparisons, but then you will have modified output values. :(  This is just one reason why this not a robust method.
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Lorem',
  1 => 'ipsum',
  2 => 'dolor',
  4 => 'amet',
  7 => 'elit',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many way is possible ! I suggere this way :

```
<?php
 $bl = array('sit', 'consectetur','adipiscing', ',', '.', ' ');
 $subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
 $a_subject = explode(' ', $subject);
 $a_subject_filtered = array_filter($a_subject, function($item) use ($bl){
     return !in_array($item, $bl);
 });
```

Comment: I have run out of downvotes, but this answer has a typo in it that will cause a parsing error and after fixing that, it will not provide the desired result.  Please update or delete this answer because it will not be helpful to future readers (in fact, it will waste their time teaching them an inefficient / indirect method).

Comment: After the edit that added the missing `;`, this answer still doesn't not provide the expected result.  Please update again or delete.